# Mingw32 opencv3.4 compile error

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake, mingw32

I've been trying to use opencv on QT. Although following every guide I could find on the internet, i was unsuccessful. Compiled opencv with CMAKE (using this guide https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows) but I have the following error:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/container_avi.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_cmu.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dshow.cpp.obj
C:\QTopencv\opencv\sources\modules\videoio\src\cap_dshow.cpp:114:21: fatal error: Aviriff.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Aviriff.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
modules\videoio\CMakeFiles\opencv_videoio.dir\build.make:146: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dshow.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dshow.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:3052: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:161: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've done these besides the guide https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows

- Unchecked `ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS` in CMAKE
- Checked `ENABLE_CXX11` in CMAKE
- In `opencv/sources/modules/videoio/src/cap_dshow.cpp` file, added `#define NO_DSHOW_STRSAFE`, before the line : `#include "DShow.h`
- In `OpenCVCompilerOptions.cmake` file;
  changed `add_extra_compiler_option(-Werror=non-virtual-dtor)` to `#add_extra_compiler_option(-Werror=non-virtual-dtor)`

No matter what I did, I couldnt succeed.

- *UPDATE* : used both cmake Windows win32-x86 and Windows win64-x64 version to compile but result is the same.
- *UPDATE* : Unchecked "BUILD_opencv_videoio" and used cmake Windows win32-x86 version to compile and then the result was successful. Now i've the library files to use.

  - checked WITH_QT
  - unchecked WITH_CUDA
  - CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE - "Debug" (without quotes).
  - Now, i am able to use QT with created libraries and here is my QT .pro file:
  - **UPDATE**: But i still haven't figured out how to compile without disabling "BUILD_opencv_videoio". Any help would be appreciated.

## -------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TX
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:\OCV\opencv_build\install\include

LIBS += -LC:\OCV\opencv_build\bin \
    libopencv_core341d \
    libopencv_highgui341d \
    libopencv_imgproc341d \
    libopencv_features2d341d \
    libopencv_calib3d341d \

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

Comment: I suppose that problem is in videoio module. When  unchecked "BUILD_opencv_videoio" in Cmake, compilation was done succesfully but i hadn't library files in the build file.(There were no libraries to use)

Comment: Can you please edit your question, adding your new discoveries? It makes easier for other people to dig into the same issue. About the last issue itself, did you perform a `make install` after building?

Comment: @SergioMonteleone in x64 cmake, calling "mingw32-make" command didnt create the library files but in cmake x86 it created the library files.